# Add a path to the Windows system Path via .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, path

I would like to create a script to add a `path` to the Windows System `Path` variable.

I searched a lot and found some possible solutions, but I'm afraid of making a mistake since I've heard reports that some commands can corrupt the local `Path` variable and then prevent the computer from booting again.

I would like to include via `.bat` the path `C:\Scripts` in the variable `Path` of the `system`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: That's the thing, I didn't try anything because I was afraid of corrupting something... I was going to try this: `setx path "%path%;C:\Scripts" /m` or this `REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Control\Session Manager\Environment /v Path /t REG_SZ /d C:\Scripts /f`

Comment: Microsoft provides free (as in air) Windows developer VM(s) that support all major hypervisors. Great way to test things you are worried about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting or modifying a (system wide) environment variable in cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/65816/setting-or-modifying-a-system-wide-environment-variable-in-cmd-exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right direction, but it seems that your problem is really
the fear of making mistakes.

`setx` is much safer than updating the registry, so is the way to go.

If you're worried about making mistakes, create a System Restore point,
so that you could always rollback to your current state.

Reference :
[How to use System Restore on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10).

Comment: @TyroneHirt - You might test your ability to actually roll back to a restoration point before you trust it to work.